# JavaFX css tags

Tags: java, css, javafx

I'm trying to make a list of boxes which a user can select through with their mouse and when one box is selected, it highlights it with a color, and all the rest of the boxes turn white. Is there an equivalent to the css tag :target in javafx like there is an equivalent to :focus(:focused) or do I have to handle selecting items in a list my own way?

Comment: There's no built-in `target` pseudoclass, but you can just create your own [CSS `PseudoClass`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/css/PseudoClass.html) on the fly.

Comment: I'm a bit confused on how to make my own CSS PseudoClass. Where do I put these code and how do I tell it to change states when clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in `target` pseudoclass, but there is an API for creating your own [CSS `PseudoClass` objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/css/PseudoClass.html).

Here is a simple example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.css.PseudoClass;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SelectableBoxes extends Application {

    private static final PseudoClass SELECTED_PSEUDOCLASS = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("selected");

    private ObjectProperty<Pane> selectedBox = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        VBox container = new VBox(5);
        container.setPadding(new Insets(20));

        int numBoxes = 5 ;
        for (int i = 0 ; i < numBoxes; i++) {
            container.getChildren().add(createBox());
        }
        ScrollPane scroller = new ScrollPane(container);
        Scene scene = new Scene(scroller, 400, 400);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("selectable-boxes.css");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private Pane createBox() {
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        pane.setMinSize(50, 50);
        pane.getStyleClass().add("box");

        pane.setOnMouseClicked(e -> selectedBox.set(pane));

        selectedBox.addListener((obs, oldSelection, newSelection) -> 
            pane.pseudoClassStateChanged(SELECTED_PSEUDOCLASS, newSelection == pane));

        return pane ;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

with the corresponding CSS file selectable-boxes.css:

```
.box {
    -fx-border-width: 1 ;
    -fx-border-color: black ;
}
.box:selected {
    -fx-background-color: blue ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This "answer" is to provide an alternate solution for the task you wish to accomplish (rather than directly answering your question regarding CSS tags).

---

For your task, you may wish to use [ToggleButtons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ToggleButton.html) in a [ToggleGroup](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ToggleGroup.html), or a [ListView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html).

Oracle provide a [ToggleButton demo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/toggle-button.htm).  By default a ToggleButton behaves a bit different from a radio button (e.g. it is possible to have nothing selected).  If you want radio button style behavior, to ensure something is always selected, you can use the bit of code at: [JDK-8090668
Need TogglePolicy for ToggleButton in ToggleGroup](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8090668)

```
toggleGroup.selectedToggleProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Toggle>() {
  public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Toggle> ov, Toggle toggle, Toggle new_toggle) {
    if (toggle != null && new_toggle == null) {
      toggle.setSelected(true);
    }
  }
});
```

The in-built controls can be styled quite extensively using CSS to get custom looks.  Refer to the [modena.css file](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u-dev/rt/file/tip/modules/controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css) for default css styles for the controls which can be overriden.